# How to add fileprovider xml file in Xamarin (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-fileprovider

I am trying to add the xml folder and an xml file named file_path.xml to implement the Fileprovider (android). However, when I add the following (Resources/xml/file_path.xml) content the application does not start anymore.

```
<paths>
        <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I get a null pointer exception as it cant read these resource. It doesnt matter whether I add the provider tag in manifest or not. I am very new in Xamarin.

Comment: You can refer this link https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/130

Comment: I saw this page. but it really doesnt work. whenever I add the xml folder and then a file in it with .xml extension, the app doesnt run anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the properties of this file, select Build Action "**AndroidResource**".

In android manifest, inside the tag application, do this:

```html
<provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
  </provider>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: I had to change the third line to `android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"` for it to work. Thanks for this!

Comment: Properties of "this" file? which file?